# Upload de arquivo, gravar o nome e caminho MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, file-upload

Salve pessoal!

To com a seguinte dúvida, ou melhor não estou sabendo fazer.

Tenho um formulário de currículo que é preenchido e o usuário anexa um arquivo.pdf

Objetivo: usuário preenche o formulario nome, email, telefone, etc... 
e anexa o currículo em pdf.

Esse arquivo pdf deve ser renomeado para o id-nome preenchido no formulário, e seu upload seja feito para a pasta arquivos.

E seja gravado no banco mysql, todos os dados do formulário, e assim o nome do arquivo e seu caminho.

Pois após isso tem painel administrativo que lista os currículos e deve mostrar o nome e caminho do arquivo para download pelo painel administrativo.

Pesquisei pela net e acabei pegando algumas partes de script e tentei montar, mas não está rolando.

Preciso da ajuda do pessoal aqui, agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Explicando o que tenho de código, e consegui resolver ate o momento, o sistema pelo menos localhost já envia o arquivo a pasta especificada, mas não da INSERT no banco de nenhuma informação.

Tenho o HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Upload de arquivos</title>
 </head>
   <body>
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label>titulo: </label><br />

           <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" /><br /><br />

              <label>Selecione o arquivo: <br />

                   <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" size="45" /></label> <br />

                      <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar Arquivo" /><br />

                           <input type="hidden" id="arquivo_id" name="arquivo_id" />

     </form>

  </body>
```

Tenho o SQL tabela arquivo e tres colunas ID - TITULO - ARQUIVO

```
CREATE TABLE `arquivo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `arquivo` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Agora o PHP:**

```
<?php
$nome_temporario=$_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$nome_real=$_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
copy($nome_temporario,"imagens/$nome_real");

$servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "curriculo";

    //Criar a conexão
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
    }

// Lendo os campos do .html
$arquivo_id = $_POST['arquivo_id'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']["name"];
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Codigo de inserção
$sql = "INSERT INTO arquivo (titulo, arquivo_id) VALUES ('$titulo', 'imagens/$arquivo')";

// Converte e Executa a query
$inserir = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


// Resultado para o .html
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '60;URL=http://localhost/loja/adm/administrativo.php?link=14'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"O arquivo foi enviado com sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";  
                }else{
                    echo "
                        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '60;URL=http://localhost/loja/adm/administrativo.php?link=14'>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Arquivo não foi enviado.\");
                        </script>
                    ";  
                }
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:

?>
```

To bem perdido no seguimento. hahahaha

Quem quiser dar uma ajuda aqui.

Aguardo e obrigado

Comment: escapa os dados quando vais inserir string ou qualquer outro dado no banco de dados: `insert x into y(nn,mm) values('{$nn}', '{$mm}')` ou usando aspas duplas e pontos, ou em vez disso usa `prepared statements` que deixa mais clara a ideia.

Comment: Desculpe mas não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: `$caminho = "imagens/" . $arquivo;`
`INSERT INTO arquivo (titulo, arquivo_id) VALUES ('{$titulo}', '{$caminho}')`. E se você está testando o código, evidentemente deveria ter os erros habilitados, para saber especificamente o que se está a passar.

Comment: Não funcionou... envia o arquivo a pasta, mas não grava nada no banco.

Comment: Qual erro está a retornar ? O teu campo `id` é `auto_increment` ?

Comment: Não retorna erro algum. Ele envia o arquivo para a pasta imagens/ - mas não insere os dados no banco.
Queria inserir o ID e nome do arquivo no banco.

Comment: executa isso na tua tabela, pelo ´phpmyadmin´ ou pelo `console`: `alter table arquivo modify id int(11) not null auto_increment;`

Comment: Obrigado amigo!
Funcionou....
So mais uma coisa, necessitava fazer com que o nome do arquivo fosse renomeado aleatoriamente.
tipo: 
09938393902.pdf

Comment: Para isso, você pode simplesmente usar [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) para essa tarefa. `print uniqid('img_');`. Mas esta função não garante que o valores serão únicos para todas as vezes que ela ocorrer.

Comment: Só números:  $nomeArquivo = str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9999999), 11, 0); ou números e letras: $nomeArquivo = uniqid(md5(rand()));  teste em http://kithomepage.com/sos/randNum-ou-Num-Letras.php

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo - Poderia me explicar no meu codigo onde inserir, pq tentei aqui e não rolou.

Comment: Esse upload é em uma pasta do servidor?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo - consegui,  so mudei o $nomeArquivo = uniqid(md5(rand()));   POR $nome_real = uniqid(md5(rand()));obrigado

Comment: Pois é, $nomeArquivo foi só um exemplo, você tinha q fazer o que fez agora, essa  variável $nome_real não está no seu código, dai coloquei um exemplo

Comment: $nome_real na primeira linha do codigo PHP - $nome_real = uniqid(md5(rand()));
copy($nome_temporario,"arquivos/$nome_real.pdf");

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, vai saber que essa variável seria o nome do arquivo. He he

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Começa modificando a tabela `arquivo` com o seguinte comando:

> alter table arquivo modify id int(11) not null auto_increment;

Com isso você adiciona o atributo `auto_increment` à tabela.

Numa consulta `SQL` devem-se sempre escapar os dados que vais inserir, usando aspas duplas `"` ou chavetas `{}`.

```
$caminho = "imagens/" . $arquivo; 

"INSERT INTO arquivo (titulo, arquivo_id) VALUES ('{$titulo}', '{$caminho}')"
ou
"INSERT INTO arquivo (titulo, arquivo_id) VALUES ('" . $titulo . "', '". $caminho . "')"
```

Para gerar nomes únicos e aleatórios, você pode usar a função [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

```
$caminho = "imagens/" . uniqid('ficheiro_') ;
```

Não há garantias de que essa função retorne sempre valores aleatórios, para isso podes usar funções próprias para isso, veja essa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string).

Comment: Show @Edilson!!! Funcionou...

Comment: @MarceloRossi ainda bem.